# How to disable OWIN/KATANA WebAPI output cache

Tags: owin, outputcache, katana

I have implemented my WebAPI using Owin/Katana.

I found out that my API calls was actually cached by the browser.

May I know how can I disable the output cache completely? There are plenty of info about WebAPI using MVC or WFC, but none of them talk about Owin/Katana.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're mixing terms. Output cache is server-side caching (not supported by HttpListener). Browsers use client side caching. You should be able to disable caching by adding a Cache-control: no-cache header.